# How do i access a class variable by parent class C#

Tags: c#

I need to access "pointHeight" of the "Bar" class by the "Point" class, I can't use interinheritance, as I will have more than one "Point" in my "Bar" class. Alternatives that can give me future problems: a static variable or putting "pointHeight" in the Point constructor. This is possible in java, with the exact same code.

```
class Bar
    {
        public int pointHeight = 50;
        private List<Point> constructPoints(int size)
        {
            int x = 10; 
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(x));
                x += 10;
            }
            return points;
        }
        class Point
        {
            private int x, y;
            public Point(int x)
            {
                this.x = x;
            }
            public void update()
            {
                this.y = pointHeight; //<--- Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit]
Thanks for the answers, but what I was looking for is apparently not possible in C#. But I solved my problem in two ways:

pass my "Bar" as a parameter in the method:

```
public void update(Bar bar)
                {
                    this.y = bar.pointHeight; //<--- Solved
                }
```

or in the class:

```
public Point(int x, Bar bar)
                {
                    this.x = x;
                    this.bar = bar;
                }
```

Once again: thanks for the help.

the reason not to use static: ill have more than one "Bar" object;
the reason not to use interinheritance: list in my "Bar" class

Comment: What problems do you foresee with using a static variable, or adding height to the `Point` constructor? Note that you can overload the constructor if you want to allow points without a height.

Comment: why not simply passing `pointHight` as parameter into the update method?

Comment: In Java, the nested class is implicitly given a reference to its parent class. This isn't automatic in C#: if you need the nested class to be able to reference an instance of parent class, pass it into its construtor: `points.Add(new Point(x, this))`. That's what Java is doing under the hood, anyway

Comment: `Point` is not a subclass btw. Also I don't see how `I will have more than one "Point" in my "Bar" class` is a valid reason not to use inheritance, seeing that you can inherit a base class as many times as you want and you can have as many point subclasses as you want

Comment: I will have more than one "Bar" class, with different "pointHeight"

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the reply, I will use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it to the method :

```
public void update(int pointHeight)
            {
                this.y = pointHeight;
            }
```

then call it this way"

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                var p = new Point(x);
                p.update(pointHeight);
                points.Add(p);
                x += 10;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Point doesn't inherit from Bar.

You've just defined it in Bar, which means you new up instances of Point with:-

```
// Set point with 3 as
var p = new Bar.Point(3);
```

Explicitly change Point so that it inherits from Bar.

Change:-

```
class Point
{
   ...
```

to

```
class Point : Bar
{
   ...
```

Then you can access **pointHeight** from an instance of Point.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want this to behave. Is `Point.y` aways equal to `pointHeight` value even if this changes, or is it initialized with the current value of `pointHeight`. Is the `update()` function necessary to sync values at specific times, or is a reference to the current `pointHeight` value enough.

#### Scenario 1 - Point is immutable with a derived property, no update needed.

```
public class Bar
{
    public int PointHeight { get; set; } = 50;

    private List<Point> ConstructPoints(int size)
    {
        int x = 10;
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new Point(this, x));
            x += 10;
        }
        return points;
    }
}
public readonly struct Point
{
    readonly Bar bar;
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get => bar.PointHeight; }

    public Point(Bar bar, int x)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.X = x;
    }
}
```

Names have been changed to conform to .NET naming standards and to make the code more readable. Also note the use of properties for greater flexibility and a `readonly struct` for `Point` to keep values immutable.

Here each point *has a reference* the `Bar` object, and pulls the `PointHeight` property from it when needed.

#### Scenario 2 - Point is mutable and sync happens on demand

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(int pointHeight = 50)
    {
        PointHeight = pointHeight;
    }

    public int PointHeight { get; set; }

    public IList<Point> ConstructPoints(int size)
    {
        int x = 10;
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new Point(x, PointHeight));
            x += 10;
        }
        return points;
    }

    public void UpdatePoints(IList<Point> points)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            points[i].Update(this);
        }
    }
}
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    public void Update(Bar bar)
    {
        this.Y = bar.PointHeight;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = new Bar(50);
        var pts = bar.ConstructPoints(16);
        bar.PointHeight = 32;

        bar.UpdatePoints(pts);
    }
}
```

This is more similar to the *op* code, but there might be issues with mutable `Point` class. I would always recommend `readonly struct` when appropriate to keep value semantics.

In this scenario (and in the code in question) it is unclear when `Update()` should be called.

Answer (score -1):

both classes look weird for me, but you You could wrap pointHeight inside a class and store a reference to the class

```
public class IntWrapper
{
    public IntWrapper(  int val ) { Value = val; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

 class Bar
{
    public int pointHeight
    {
        get { return _intWrapper.Value; }
        set {_intWrapper.Value=value;}
    } 
    
    private IntWrapper _intWrapper = new IntWrapper(50);
     
    private List<Point> constructPoints(int size)
    {
        int x = 10;
            
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new Point(x, _intWrapper));
            x += 10;
        }
        return points;
    }
    class Point
    {
        private int x, y;
        
        private IntWrapper _wrapper;
    
        
        public Point(int x, IntWrapper wrapper)
        {
            this.x = x;
            
            _wrapper=wrapper;
        }
        public void update()
        {
            y = _wrapper.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

or you can use the whole Bar class as a wrapper as well, but I don' t know what fits better for you

```
 points.Add(new Point(x, this));
```